# Save XML file in a Network Location

Tags: php, xml

I have a script that saves an xml file a folder on the local server in the `C:\xml`.
This works, but I now need to save the XML files in a network location.  It could look like this

`$save_path = "192.168.0.5\\C:\xml\\";`

or this

`$save_path = "Z:\\xml\\";`

where the Z would be a mapped network drive to the xml folder which is on the C Drive of the remote computer. But it does not seem to work, any ideas or comments that I could try please?
Thanks
Paul.

Comment: Make sure path is correct and valid. Make sure you have access to this folder. Do you have any error message?

Comment: the first of the above is totally incorrect syntax for a network share, it would be more like `\\192.168.0.5\xml` assuming the folder has been shared correctly with appropriate permissions. Also, each backslash probably needs to be scaped so more like `\\\\192.168.0.5\\xml`

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can share the error message apache(or other servers ) should have access to the drive you want to save files to.

Comment: Hi, Thabnks for the replys, I dont get any error messages, as its basically just gets an array from the PHP/MySQL database and converts it to an XML file. I shall try it with the extra backslashes. Thank You